# Bigquery Where = ANY

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, grafana

I am querying Bigquery using Grafana, In Grafana i use a text box variable(SrcAddr) to select certain values.

`Select * from flow_tables where SrcAddr = '100.100.100.1'`

if the User did not provide any input then all the IP addresses need to be selected. What value needs to be used to select all the IPs?

`Select * from flow_tables where SrcAddr = 'ANY'`

I tried using *, ANY, "." but it didnot help.

Comment: Can you change it to `where SrcAddr = SrcAddr`, which will always be true?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that if the User did not provide any input it returns null - use something like below

```
Select * from flow_tables where SrcAddr = ifnull(<whatever user selected>, SrcAddr)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to query for all addresses first and then use them to filter the actual results if no input was made into the text box. If there is an input, use that.

Example:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM your_table
WHERE SrcAddr IN UNNEST(
  (
    SELECT CASE
    WHEN '${your_variable}' = '' THEN (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(SrcAddr) FROM your_table)
    ELSE (SELECT ['${your_variable}'])
    END
  )
)
```

(Assuming you named your variable `your_variable` and the column to filter by is `SrcAddr` and that column is a `STRING` column in the table `your_table`.)